# Ideal database for a minimalist blog engine

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, rdbms

So I'm designing this blog engine and I'm trying to just keep my blog data without considering comments or membership system or any other type of multi-user data.

The blog itself is surrounded around 2 types of data, the first is the actual blog post entry which consists of: **title**, **post body**, **meta data (mostly dates and statistics)**, so it's really simple and can be represented by simple json object. The second type of data is the blog admin configuration and personal information. Comment system and other will be implemented using ***disqus***.

My main concern here is the ability of such engine to scale with spiked visits *(I know you might argue this but lets take it for granted)*. So since I've started this project I'm moving well with the rest of my stack except the data layer. Now I've been having this dilemma choosing the database, I've considered MongoDB but some reviews and articles/benchmarking were suggesting slow reads after collections read certain size. Next I was looking at Redis and using its persistence features RDB and AOF, while Redis is good at both fast reading/writing I'm afraid of using it because I'm not familiar with it. And this whole search keeps going on to things like ***["PostgreSQL 9.4 is now faster than MongoDB for storing JSON documents"](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1q3skb/postgresql_94_is_now_faster_than_mongodb_for/)*** etc.

So is there any way I can settle this issue for good? considering that I only need to represent my data in key,value structure and only require fast reading but not writing and the ability to be fault tolerant.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would start small and not try to optimize for big data just yet. A lot of blogs you read about the downsides of a NoSQL solution are around large data sets - or people that are trying to do relational things with a database designed for de-normalized data.

My list of databases to consider:

1. Mongo. It has huge community support and based on recent funding - it's going to be around for a while. It runs very well on a single instance and a basic replica set. It's easy to set up and free, so it's worth spending a day or two running your own tests to settle the issue once and for all. Don't trust a blog.
2. Couchbase. Supports key/value storage and also has persistence to disk. http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/features Also has had some recent funding so hopefully that means stability. =)
3. CouchDB/PouchDB. You can use PouchDB purely on the client side and it can connect to a server side CouchDB. CouchDB might not have the same momentum as Mongo or Couchbase, but it's an actively supported product and does key/value with persistence to disk.
4. Riak. http://basho.com/riak/.  Another NoSQL that scales and is a key/value store.

You can install and run a proof-of-concept on all of the above products in a few hours. I would recommend this for the following reasons:

1. A given database might scale and hit your points, but be unpleasant to use. Consider picking a database that feels fun! Sort of akin to picking Ruby/Python over Java because the syntax is nicer.
2. Your use case and domain will be fairly unique. Worth testing various products to see what fits best.
3. Each database has quirks and you won't find those until you actually try one. One might have quirks that are passable, one will have quirks that are a show stopper.
4. The benefit of trying all of them is that they *all* support schemaless data, so if you write JSON, you can use all of them! No need to create objects in your code for each database.
5. If you abstract the database correctly in code, swapping out data stores won't be that painful. In other words, your code will be happier if you make it easy to swap out data stores.

Comment: what do you think about Redis as a candidate? I've tried Mongo but the random articles on Hacker News for example made me free using it :(

I've yet to try Couchbase and CouchDB, but I will before I decide on this.

Comment: I love Redis from my brief usage of it. It also has great backing behind it and can have persistence turned on. It also provides much more than simple key/value functionality. I know Stack Overflow uses Redis, so it can't be that bad. =)

Comment: yep I've decided to run with it since it's doing well with RBD and AOF. Things are quite simple so far and I just love it. I've decided to use it anyway since I can always create a database mapper that would plugin some of the engines you mentioned. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is only an option for really simple CMSes, but it sounds like that's what you're building.

If your blog is super-simple as you describe and your main concern is very high traffic then the best option might be to avoid a database entirely and have your CMS generate static files instead.  By doing this, you eliminate all your database concerns completely.

It's not the best option if you're doing anything dynamic or complex, but in this small use case it might fit the bill.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's actually a nice idea. So you're suggesting I create something like json files and do dumps in some directory? but what about admin data and authentication? I dont think hashing/salt of admin password for example is enough when someone can just open and read the file.

Comment: I would skip json completely and let the CMS generate the entire, full rendered html page.   For authentication, you could just store a salted one-way hash of the admin password in a config file that isn't accessible to the outside world and have it lock the CMS after N incorrect login attempts.  You could even take the entire CMS portion off the public server if you wanted and treat the CMS as a desktop client that publishes to the web over sftp.

Comment: I don't see how I can fit a CMS with Go and AngularJS. if the data is coming from a restful API built with Go and the view is generated by Angular I presume using a CMS would mean I need to change my development stack, and that's not part of the plan :)

Thank for the suggestion though.

Comment: What are you using AngularJS for?  Based on your project description there doesn't seem to be any need for ajax at all.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that my implementation involves using a CMS, the idea is that I want to build this engine with specific stack and it must act as a single-page app so this is why I'm using Angular.